# Melt a dataframe using separation and create from one row many rows

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(text = c("text2?????something more?????additional"), id = c("1?????2?????3"))
```

how is it possible to melt using the separation ????? and create new rows like this:

```
data.frame(text = c("text2", "something more", "additional"), id = c(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyr)
# fixing the data
d = data.frame(text = c("text2?????something more?????additional"), id = c("1?????2?????3"))
d %>% separate_rows(everything(), sep = "\\?+")
#             text id
# 1          text2  1
# 2 something more  2
# 3     additional  3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- 
  data.frame(text = c("text2?????something more?????additional"), id = c("1?????2?????3"))

as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) strsplit(as.character(x), '\\?+')[[1]]))

#             text id
# 1          text2  1
# 2 something more  2
# 3     additional  3
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `unnest` and `str_extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)   
df1 %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), str_extract_all, "[^?]+")) %>% 
    unnest(everything())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  text           id   
#  <chr>          <chr>
#1 text2          1    
#2 something more 2    
#3 additional     3
```